# Most efficient safe way to cast std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<Base>> to std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<Derived>>

Tags: c++, casting, c++17, shared-ptr

We currently store several different collections of data models like so:

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<int64_t, std::shared_ptr<DataObject>>> models;
```

The string maps to a known list of types and this is all dealt with by serialization. The nested map contains a collection of "Object Id" and associated (deserialized) std::shared_ptr<DataObject>

DataObject is a base class which we have several types derived from.

We have a method to get all DataObjects of a given type:

```
static std::map<int64_t, std::shared_ptr<DataObject>> *getAll(std::string type);
```

This simply returns a pointer to the map at a given "type" key.

Today I encountered a code review to add the following which I believe invokes UB but seems to function. This has me a little nervous and looking for an efficient solution:

```
template <typename M>
static std::map<int64_t, std::shared_ptr<M>> *getAll(const std::string &type) {
    auto castObjectMap = reinterpret_cast<std::map<int64_t, std::shared_ptr<M>>*>(getAll(type));
    return castObjectMap;
}
```

The benefit to casting like this is that it involves no looping or copying (as far as I can tell), it's a simple pointer cast. That's fantastic. But I don't think it's portable or safe, though I don't know what the best portable and safe alternative would be.

I have a simplified version of a toy version of this question below, it does actually spit out the correct output as expected:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

struct Base {
    Base(){}
    virtual ~Base(){}

    Base(int u):x(u){}

    int x = 0;
};

struct Derived : public Base {
    Derived(){}
    Derived(int u, int v):Base(u),y(v){}
    int y = 0;
};

int main() {
    map<int, shared_ptr<Base>> test {
        {0, make_shared<Derived>(2, 3)},
        {1, make_shared<Derived>(4, 5)},
        {2, make_shared<Derived>(6, 7)}
    };

    map<int, shared_ptr<Derived>> *castVersion = reinterpret_cast<map<int, shared_ptr<Derived>>*>(&test);

    for(auto&&kv : *castVersion){
        cout << kv.first << ": " << kv.second->x << ", " << kv.second->y << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My question is if there's a good way to do this which doesn't involve a lot of copying, or if there's a clean way to do so at least. We are using C++17 presently.

Comment: It certainly is undefined behavior. What to do instead is a bit trickier.

Comment: You certainly can't safely do a reinterpret cast between two entirely unrelated classes.

Comment: You should use likes of std::transform to convert between different container types but it involves copying.

Comment: Rather than casting the map, you should cast elements retrieved from the map.  Then it is safe.  (Not that I like the idea of casting anything).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It won't give exactly the same interface, but a similar but safer idea that comes to mind is using [`boost::transform_iterator`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/iterator/doc/html/iterator/specialized/transform.html) to create iterators that transparently handle converting the `shared_ptr` pointers within the map.

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>

template <class Derived, class Iterator>
class downcast_pair_iterator
    : public boost::transform_iterator<
        std::pair<
            typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type::first_type,
            const std::shared_ptr<Derived>
        > (*)(Iterator),
        Iterator>
{
public:
    using base_value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type;
    using key_type = const typename base_value_type::first_type;
    using base_mapped_type = typename base_value_type::second_type;
    using mapped_type = const std::shared_ptr<Derived>;
    using value_type = std::pair<key_type, mapped_type>;

private:
    template <typename T>
    static T* shared_to_raw(const std::shared_ptr<T>&); // undefined
    static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<
        std::remove_pointer_t<
            decltype(shared_to_raw(std::declval<base_mapped_type&>()))>,
        Derived>);

    static value_type convert(const base_value_type& pair_in)
    {
        return value_type(pair_in.first,
            std::static_pointer_cast<Derived>(pair_in.second));
    }
public:
    explicit downcast_pair_iterator(Iterator iter)
        : transform_iterator(iter, &convert) {}
};

template <class Derived, class Iterator>
auto make_downcast_pair_iter(Iterator iter)
{
    return downcast_pair_iterator<Derived, Iterator>(iter);
}

template <class Derived, class Range>
class downcast_pair_range
{
public:
    explicit downcast_pair_range(Range& c)
        : source_ref(c) {}

    auto begin() const {
        using std::begin;
        return make_downcast_pair_iter<Derived>(begin(source_ref));
    }
    auto end() const {
        using std::end;
        return make_downcast_pair_iter<Derived>(end(source_ref));
    }

private:
    Range& source_ref;
};

template <class Derived, class Range>
auto make_downcast_pair_range(Range& r)
{
    return downcast_pair_range<Derived, Range>(r);
}
template <class Derived, class Range>
auto make_downcast_pair_range(const Range &r)
{
    return downcast_pair_range<Derived, const Range>(r);
}
```

Then your example `main` could become:

```
int main() {
    std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<Base>> test {
        {0, std::make_shared<Derived>(2, 3)},
        {1, std::make_shared<Derived>(4, 5)},
        {2, std::make_shared<Derived>(6, 7)}
    };

    for (auto&& kv : make_downcast_pair_range<Derived>(test)){
        std::cout << kv.first << ": "
                  << kv.second->x << ", " << kv.second->y << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This avoids making any second container object, and does not involve undefined behavior when used correctly. Using the transforming iterators will mostly result in the same machine code as the unsafe cast, except that a dereference does create a new `shared_ptr<Derived>` object, which will involve a little reference-counting overhead.  [See the full working program on coliru.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81a09143d4b57ae5)

In addition to using `make_downcast_pair_range<Derived>(some_map)` as shown in the range-based `for` above, `make_downcast_pair_iterator<Derived>` can be used directly to get transforming iterators for other purposes, for example from the result of a map's `find(k)`. And given a transforming iterator, you can get back to an iterator for the real map using `iter.base()`, for example to pass to the map's `erase(iter)`.

Of course, using the result of [`std::static_pointer_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast) is still undefined behavior if the pointers aren't actually pointing at `Derived` objects. If there's any concern someone might use the wrong "derived" template argument when getting objects, or that the maps might somehow end up containing pointers to the wrong derived object types, you could change the `downcast_pair_iterator<D, I>::convert` private function to use `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` instead, then throw or abort if the result is a null pointer.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, and I'm likely going to actually create a downcast_map_wrapper instead to allow for value[key] interface casting. Thanks for pointing me on the right path.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly use the std::map constructor taking a pair of iterators because the conversion is attempting to cast from Base to Derived which cannot be done implicitly, but you can run an std::transform safely. This does involve copying but has the benefit of *not* being undefined behavior.

```
template <typename M>
static std::map<int64_t, std::shared_ptr<M>> getAll(const std::string &type) {
    auto* source = getAll(type);
    std::map<int64_t, std::shared_ptr<M>> castMap;
    std::transform(source->begin(), source->end(), std::inserter(castMap, castMap.end()), [](auto& kv) {
        return std::pair<const int, std::shared_ptr<M>>(kv.first, std::static_pointer_cast<M>(kv.second));
    });
    return castMap;
}
```

Comment: The pointer does not dangle, the lifespan is managed by the object. It is not safe to hold onto outside of that frame, but the lifespan is owned by the surrounding map.

Comment: No, `castMap` is a local variable that goes out of scope as soon as the function returns.  Returning a pointer to it is definitely creating a dangling pointer.

Comment: Ah, fair enough, thanks for the catch. I haven't checked this in, was just providing the general cast in the sample code and quickly copied it over to answer. I'll update my answer.

To be fair it was trying to return a pointer address, but the return would have been a value so the sample above wouldn't compile at all. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you cannot just cast casually like this.  `std::map<int64_t, std::shared_ptr<M>>` and `std::map<int64_t, std::shared_ptr<DataObject>>` are entirely different types.  You cannot make a pointer point to an unrelated class without triggering UB.  You have to make a copy somehow.

If you are converting from pointers to the derived class to pointers to the base class, you can directly do:

```
std::map<int64_t, std::shared_ptr<M>> new_map{old_map.begin(), old_map.end()};
```

This takes advantage of the fact `shared_ptr`s convert when needed.  If you are doing it the other way around, then you can rely on implicit conversion, so use `static_pointer_cast`.

Comment: You can go from Derived -> Base implicitly, but not Base -> Derived as the question was asking unfortunately.

Comment: @M2tM Oops.  Thanks.